# Using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 in Asp.Net for creating a meeting

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I am Using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 in Asp.Net for creating a meeting.
Following is my event data.
But it gives error that 'Invalid conference type value'.

```
            var newEvent = new Event
            {
                Summary = Title,
                Location = "My Location",
                Start = new EventDateTime
                {
                    DateTime = Start,
                    TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
                },
                End = new EventDateTime
                {
                    DateTime = End,
                    TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
                },
                Attendees = new List<EventAttendee>
                {
                    new EventAttendee { Email = "abc@gmail.com" },
                },
                ConferenceData = new ConferenceData
                {
                    CreateRequest = new CreateConferenceRequest()
                    {
                        RequestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                        ConferenceSolutionKey = new ConferenceSolutionKey()
                        {
                            Type = "hangoutsMeet",
                        },
                    }
                }
            };
```